# set and get queue values using uvm_config_db

Tags: uvm

I have been trying to set queue values in config db at run phase of test and trying to get that using uvm_config_db in sequence but I am not successful in this(nothing is been obtained in the get call from uvm_config_db), only below mentioned error appears, please let me know were I am going wrong and how to correct it. Also there seems to be typographic error in UVM_ERROR from BCL, instead of " [RNFNAME] Resrouce" it should be " [RNFNAME] Resource".

```
UVM_INFO ../tests/du_test_sanity.sv(116) @ 100000.0 ps: uvm_test_top [QUEUE_VAL] qu : '{3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 1, -1, 0, 0}
UVM_ERROR @ 100000.0 ps: reporter [RNFNAME] Resrouce named  not found in name map; cannot change its search priority
```

In test run_phase using the following

```
 `uvm_info("QUEUE_VAL",$sformatf("qu : %p",qu), UVM_NONE);
  foreach(qu[i])
  uvm_config_db #(bit [15:0])::set(uvm_root::get(),"*",qu[i],qu[i]);
```

In the seqeunce I am trying to read the queue values using get call inside task body();

```
    foreach(qu[i])
    uvm_config_db #(bit [15:0])::get(uvm_root::get(), "*", qu[i], temp[i])
    foreach(temp[i])    
   `uvm_info("COMP", $sformatf("string1 : %0h", temp[i]), UVM_LOW);
```

Also please let me know if any other feasible method to pass queue values from run_phase to sequence

Comment: Your config_db set function doesn't make sense. The third argument to set is a string, which is the field name. https://www.vmmcentral.com/uvm_vmm_ik/files3/base/uvm_config_db-svh.html#uvm_config_db.set

Answer (score 0):

3rd argument of the `uvm_config_db` is a string.

The full signature of the set method is `void uvm_config_db #( type T = int )::set( uvm_component cntxt , string inst_name , string field_name , T value );`

- `T` is the type of the element being configured - usually a virtual interface or a configuration object.
- `cntxt` and `inst_name` together form a scope that is used to locate the resource within the database. The scope is formed by appending the instance name to the full hierarchical name of the context, like {cntxt.get_full_name(),".",inst_name}.
- `field_name` supplies the name of the resource
- `value` is the thing which is actually going to be put into the database.

Here is an example.

```
interface abc a1( clk , reset );
...
uvm_config_db #(virtual abc)::set(null, "*", "my_vir_inf", a1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in the component using

```
foreach(qu[i])
uvm_config_db#(int)::set(this,"*",$sformatf("qu[%0d]",i),qu[i]);
```

and get in other component using

```
foreach(qu[i])
uvm_config_db#(int)::get(this,"*",$sformatf("qu[%0d]",i),temp[i]);
```